# jQuery Onclick function wont work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My JQuery seen have some error that try added to html that generated from WordPress, can anyone help to fix it? Thanks

HTML code: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQAp9.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('a[href="#nav_menu-10"]').click(function(){
    onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggle');"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: *"HTML code: link"* Show code, markup, etc. as **text**, not as *pictures* of text (and **in** the question, not linked). More: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: nope, I try added the script but not work

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `this.classList.toggle('toggle');` directly in the code rather than a string assignment to `onclick`

```
jQuery('a[href="#nav_menu-10"]').click(function(){
  this.classList.toggle('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your logic is simply setting a variable named `onclick` to a string. You're not actually doing anything to the element.

For this to work you need to amend the `classList` of the element referenced by the `this` keyword directly within the click handler, like this:

```
$('a[href="#nav_menu-10"]').click(function(){
  this.classList.toggle('toggle');
});
```

Or in pure jQuery:

```
$('a[href="#nav_menu-10"]').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle');
});
```